# Is there a way to emulate a wireless card in qemu / kvm?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, network-interface

Is there a way to emulate a wireless card in qemu / kvm?  Or is there no point to this?
Is it considered just another interface?

Comment: I don't think it's that there isn't any point to it, it's just that it's such a specific thing to want to do that it's not likely to have been developed. One would also question what problem you would be solving. Most of the time a VM's "NIC" is just how it's basic network connectivity has been presented to the system, it showing up as a NIC is just a means to that end.

Comment: Define _emulate a wireless card_. There is the `mac80211_hwsim` linux kernel module.

Comment: Emulate wireless card: Add a NIC to a vm that has the ability to simulate having a physical card; you'd be able to change how strong the signal is and things like this.

Comment: I guess I should specify that I'm running my VMs with Virtual Machine Manager and I don't see one in the list when adding an interface.

Comment: Then [mac80211_hwsim](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/mac80211_hwsim) is maybe what you want. It's not specific to a VM but a loadable kernel module to simulate radios usable with `hostapd` and `wpa_supplicant` etc.

Comment: There definitely is a point to do that. Mastering this would allow us to test wifi software and wifi configurations properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloonix from version 42.03 does the wifi inside the guests. For this it uses the mac80211_hwsim module and a software running in the guest, this software transmits the signal to host and then to other guests.

Comment: Do you know which software is that? Thanks!